# Expected undefined to equal 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

**Technologies Used:** Karma/Jasmine, Angular2

**service.ts**

```
Injectable()
export class Service { 

    constructor(private http: Http) { }
      getGoogle(): Observable<any>{
        console.log("Inside service");
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');    
     }}
```

**Please ignore the Typos and all the imports are made correctly.API is getting called correctly in the UI.**

**service.spec.ts**

```
describe('Provider:Service', () => {

const HERO_ONE = 'HeroNrOne';
const HERO_TWO = 'WillBeAlwaysTheSecond';

    let lastConnection;
    let service;


    beforeEach(() => {
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
            { provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
            { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },
            Http,
            Service

        ]);
        service = injector.get(Service);
        let backend = injector.get(ConnectionBackend) as MockBackend;
        backend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => lastConnection = connection);

    }); 

  it('getGoogle() should return the data in json format', fakeAsync(() => {
        console.log('1');
        let result:String[];
        service.getGoogle().toPromise().then((heroes:String[]) => result = heroes);
        lastConnection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
            body:JSON.stringify({data: [HERO_ONE, HERO_TWO]}),
          })));
        tick();
        console.log(result[0]);
        console.log('3');

        expect(result.length).toEqual(2, 'should contain given amount of 
        heroes');   //this spec is failing because results does is not getting the response.  

    }));
```

The `result:String[]` is not getting the response that is provided.

Comment: The test ends right after calling `getGoogle`. I believe the requests did not finish before the test did. Why do you unittest a call to external service? I think it should be mocked.

Comment: It means I have to make a mock response and pass it to the created mockbackend as a mockresponse?

Comment: understood! Thanks

Comment: @dzejdzej Can you solve it now? I have provided the mockresponse.But its not fetching it.

Comment: I'm not an expert in testing (unluckily). I can see two ways of solving it:
1) Refactor your test to mimic Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests
2) Mock `XHRBackend` as done here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html, which what I'm using (just slightly different from your implementation). I think the reason your solution doesn't work is because you're mocking an abstract class `ConnectionBackend`.